OpenWeatherMap measurments get request returns empty array right after sending data
Trying to work my personal weather station into an OpenWeatherMap station, but when I try to check the data, it returns an empty array
I tried using cURL and Python, but to no avail either way
curl -X POST "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/measurements?appid=********************************" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[{\"station_id\": \"************************\",\"dt\": 1713389830, \"temperature\": 23.33, \"pressure\": 825.183, \"humidity\": 17.3}]"


curl -X GET "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/measurements?station_id=************************&appid=********************************&type=d&limit=10&from=1713389810&to=1713389840"
[]

from datetime import datetime

import requests 

now: datetime = datetime.now()
ts: int = int(now.timestamp())

weather_get = requests.get('***************************') # Get the data from the weather station

if weather_get.status_code == 200:
    weather = weather_get.json()
    
    weather_data = [
    {
        "station_id": "************************",
        "dt": ts,
        "temperature": weather['external']['temp'],
        "pressure": weather['external']['pressure'],
        "humidity": weather['external']['humidity'],
        "wind_speed": weather['external']['wind_speed'],
        "wind_gust": weather['external']['wind_speed']
    }
    ]

    print(weather_data)
    
    post = requests.post("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/measurements?appid=********************************", headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"}, json=weather_data) # Send data to OpenWeatherMap station
    get = requests.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/measurements?station_id=************************&appid=********************************&type=d&limit=1000&from=" + str(ts - 1000) + "&to=" + str(ts + 1000)) # Check data
    print(post.status_code) # Should print 204 
    print(get.json()) # Should print the same output as the weather_data variable

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
python send_weather_data.py
[{'station_id': '************************', 'dt': 1713393257, 'temperature': 24.97999954, 'pressure': 825.2692871, 'humidity': 16.79999924, 'wind_speed': 0, 'wind_gust': 0}]
204
[]


It shouldn't be the API Token or the station_id, because both of them are correct
Does anyone have any idea as to why it's not working and/or how to fix it?
